# Blazor InputData resets after I start typing

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following code in a Blazor Server App form

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="_myclass.DateCreated" class ="form_control" min ="1753-01-01" max="9999-12-31 id="CreationDate" />

public class MyClass 
{
    public Datetime? DateCreated{get;set;}
}
```

The issue is when I try to edit the date, if it is set to

> 07/31/2022 and I click in the date component and try change the month, if I type 01 it changes the value to
> 01/dd/yyyy

. It has reset the whole date. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Why is your DateTime nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the "?" from `public DateTime? DateCreated{get;set;}`

Comment: but its a null able field in the DB?

Comment: Set a default value for the model so it accepts null from db but converts it to something like the min value for example. There is no other solution that would avoid changing the value to 01/dd/yyyy without removing the "?"

Comment: Tried changing DateTime? to Nullable<DateTime> but no difference

Comment: how would that work though setting a default value? i would still need null in the db?

Comment: DateTime defaults to DateTime.MinValue, you can try by calling default(DateTime). In your data access layer or in you SQL you can check for the minvalues and convert them to null when inserting/updating.
This seems to be a lot of work to solve your small cosmetic issue though.
Perhaps creating a model for the edit context used in your EditForm that has non-nullable DateTime i.e. separate models for data access and edit context?